# AFNetworking PUT request occasionally doesn't finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

When I PUT a JSON object to my subclassed `AFHTTPClient` using this method,

`- (void)putPath:parameters:success:failure:`

It works 95% of the time. BUT, every once in a while, the operation never finishes. i.e., neither the success nor failure block are called. I've verified this phenomena for at least up to 5-10 minutes with no response.

Is there some other contingency I'm supposed to be checking for? I would think within some reasonable 60-second timeout, this request would have to finish definitively in some way. Also, I believe I've seen this behavior with plain `AFJSONRequestOperations` that don't use a custom `AFHTTPClient`.

Anyone seen anything like this before?